# $_GET variable Array with MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, get

I am having trouble figuring out how to work an if statement into my PHP containing a MySQL Query. Here's what I have so far (it's unfinished):

```
$industry = $_GET['industry'];
$location = $_GET['location'];
$position = $_GET['position'];
$region = $_GET['region'];

if($industry=="any"){

}

if($location=="any"){

}

if($position=="any"){

}

if($region=="any"){

}

$sql_cat = "
SELECT *
FROM jobs
WHERE industry_cat='$industry' && location_cat='$location' && position_cat='$position' && region_cat='$region'
ORDER BY id DESC
";
$result_cat = $mysqli->query($sql_cat);
$num_rows_cat = mysqli_num_rows($result_cat);
```

Basically, what I'm trying to say is that if any of the variables are set to 'any' then I want those variables to represent all the possibilities (there's like five possibilites in the form for each variable). I figured I'd use arrays in the where clause (like WHERE industry IN ($industry)) but then it wouldn't work if someone actually did pick a variable.

I may be a little off track but am having trouble wrapping my mind around it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: can you please provide some more information what you really want

Comment: what is your variables (you said five possibilities)?

Comment: It's just a search form that people submit and there's an option for 'any' which I would like to represent all possibilites for that variable when I'm querying my database. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Sithu, for the purposes of this, we can just use "661" "662" "663" and "664" as the variables that can be chosen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I did not misunderstand your question, I would do this.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE 1";
if($industry !== "any"){
    $sql .= " AND industry_cat = '$industry'"
}
if($location !== "any"){
    $sql .= " AND location_cat = '$location'"
}
if($position !== "any"){
    $sql .= " AND position_cat = '$position'"
}
if($region !== "any"){
    $sql .= " AND region_cat = '$region'"
}
$sql .= " ORDER BY id DESC"
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

You can remove single quote around the variables in the query if you are sure they are integer.

Comment: Now, let's say someone actually chooses something other than 'any' on one of those, is it still going to show for that variable?

Comment: @MxmastaMills, if 661 chosen for industry, for example, the first condition will resolve this by adding a condition `AND industry_cat = '661'` to the query. Note that you can use `!=` instead of `!==`. The later is exact match including data type. You could try it :)

Comment: I am receiving an error: "Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /example/example.php on line 57" when the search results are chosen and no results come up. It's displaying things correctly (the row count as 0, etc.) but it's giving me the error message on the page as well. I'm trying to think it through but can't figure out why the result would be empty...

Comment: @MxmastaMills, it is because the correct mysqli result is not given to `mysqli_num_rows()`. Probably, a query failed. Check your queries in your page. I recommend to wrap your query exec with `if`, for example, `if($result = mysqli_query($sql)){ $count = mysqli_num_rows($result); }else{ echo mysqli_error($result); `, i.e., if `$sql` failed, it won't give such error. Please also note that you use mysqli object or mysqli functions ? i.e., `$mysqli->query($sql)` or `mysqli_query($sql)`;

Comment: Ah, you're right. There was a slight typo in the code above (iregion_cat instead of region_cat) and I hadn't noticed it previously. Thanks again for your help, it's saved me a lot of time and actually taught me a bunch too!

Answer (score 0):

Build your where clause gradually

```
$industry = $_GET['industry'];
$location = $_GET['location'];
$position = $_GET['position'];
$region = $_GET['region'];

if($industry!="any"){
    $where[] = 'industry_cat=?';
    $where_args[] = $industry;
}

if($location!="any"){
    $where[] = 'location_cat=?';
    $where_args[] = $location;
}

if($position!="any"){
    $where[] = 'position_cat=?';
    $where_args[] = $position;
}

if($region!="any"){
    $where[] = 'region_cat=?';
    $where_args[] = $region;
}

$where_clause = implode(' and ', $where);

$sql_cat = "
SELECT *
FROM jobs
where $whereclause
ORDER BY id DESC
";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql_cat);
```